# Why isn't this random?

Tags: vb.net, random

I am trying to produce a set of 10 random numbers using VB.net using the Random class.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 10
    Console.WriteLine("Random {0}: {1}", i, (New Random).Next(1, 100))
Next
```

This code iterates 10 times, each using a new instance of a random class to generate an integer between 1 and 100, the outputting it to the console.

However, the results are definitely not random:

[image: Console Output]

Its worth noting that the number 34 changes each time the subroutine is run.

Why is this?
Is it because I am creating a new instance of the random class on each iteration? If so why does this cause a problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the MSDN documentation describes why this happens fairly well. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx

> By default, the parameterless constructor of the Random class uses the system clock to generate its seed value, while its parameterized constructor can take an Int32 value based on the number of ticks in the current time. However, because the clock has finite resolution, using the parameterless constructor to create different Random objects in close succession creates random number generators that produce identical sequences of random numbers. The following example illustrates that two Random objects that are instantiated in close succession generate an identical series of random numbers.

Comment: This is the right answer & thanks for the article - its interesting to know how VB generates random integers, do you know if it uses the same method when using `Randomize()` and `Rnd()`?

Answer (score 2):

This will fix it. The `Random` class uses a seed (which is just an integer) to generate its Random numbers. Two Random objects with the same seed will generate the same numbers. Using a `Static` variable fixes this problem.

Now, if you don't provide a seed in the constructor, the default is that the seed is taken from `Environment.TickCount`.

```
Static rnd As New Random
For i As Integer = 0 To 10
  Console.WriteLine("Random {0}: {1}", i, (rnd.Next(1, 100))
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
Static r As New Random
For i As Integer = 0 To 10
  Console.WriteLine("Random {0}: {1}", i, (r.Next(1, 100))
Next
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The random number generation starts from a seed value. If the same
>   seed is used repeatedly, the same series of numbers is generated. One
>   way to produce different sequences is to make the seed value
>   time-dependent, thereby producing a different series with each new
>   instance of Random. By default, the parameterless constructor of the
>   Random class uses the system clock to generate its seed value, while
>   its parameterized constructor can take an Int32 value based on the
>   number of ticks in the current time. However, because the clock has
>   finite resolution, using the parameterless constructor to create
>   different Random objects in close succession creates random number
>   generators that produce identical sequences of random numbers.